# Assistance with Select-Object -Last 1 and filenames

Tags: powershell

I have the following code which checks a directory for "a_file.xls", "b_file.xls", "c_file.xls", and so on.

Depending on what is found it will rename "file.xls" to the next letter, example if the above three A,B,C files are found then the next time "file.xls is renamed it will become "d_file.xls"

I need to adapt this code to include a datestamp in the renamed file using `$fileDate = (get-date).ToString('MMdd')`

Here's the code that does what I described above.

```
$fileDate = (get-date).ToString('MMdd')

$dir = "\\server\folder123"

$var = (Get-ChildItem -Path $dir\*_file.xls | Select-Object -Last 1).BaseName.Split('_')[0]

switch ($var) {
   "a" {$fileLetter = "b"; break}
   "b" {$fileLetter = "c"; break}
   "c" {$fileLetter = "d"; break}
   "d" {$fileLetter = "e"; break}
   "e" {$fileLetter = "f"; break}
   "f" {$fileLetter = "g"; break}
   "g" {$fileLetter = "h"; break}
   "h" {$fileLetter = "i"; break}
   "i" {$fileLetter = "j"; break}
   "j" {$fileLetter = "k"; break}
   "k" {$fileLetter = "l"; break}
   "l" {$fileLetter = "m"; break}
   "m" {$fileLetter = "n"; break}
   "n" {$fileLetter = "o"; break}
   "o" {$fileLetter = "p"; break}
   "p" {$fileLetter = "q"; break}
   "q" {$fileLetter = "r"; break}
   "r" {$fileLetter = "s"; break}
   "s" {$fileLetter = "t"; break}
   "t" {$fileLetter = "u"; break}
   "u" {$fileLetter = "v"; break}
   "v" {$fileLetter = "w"; break}
   "w" {$fileLetter = "x"; break}
   "x" {$fileLetter = "y"; break}
   "y" {$fileLetter = "z"; break}
   default {$fileLetter = "a"; break}
}
$renameFrom = $dir + "\file.xls"
$renameTo = $fileLetter + "_file.xls"

Rename-item $dir\"file.xls" $renameTo
```

The $renameTo is going to become...
`$renameTo = $fileDate + $fileLetter + "_file.xls"`

When I change to this, my `Select-Object -Last 1` becomes a problem, it doesn't find the last used letter. Instead it just finds file.xls as the last and then tries to rename to a file that already exists: Example 1120a_file.xls.

How can I fix this? I tried `| select-string` with a regex pattern but that wasn't working. Also tried `| Where-Object` with regex as well and that wasn't working either.

Any suggestions on how to best achieve this?

What is happening is I'm unzipping a file that contains file.xls, there could be multiple files, sometimes not. The files need to be renamed to MMddA_File.xls, MMddB_File.xls, MMddC_File.xls and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only care about the letter in the file name, not also about the timestamp, you can try the following:

```
# Extract the alphabetically highest letter from the existing file names.
# * -creplace '.*([a-z])_.*', '$1' matches each base name in full,
#   and captures a lowercase letter before "_" in the 1st capture group,
#   which is then used to replace the input string ('$1'), effectively
#   returning only the letter from each base name.
# * The letters are then sorted in descending order, and the first one
#   (the highest) is returned.
$fileLetter = 
  (Get-Item -Path $dir\*_file.xls).BaseName -creplace '.*([a-z])_.*', '$1' | 
    Sort-Object -Descending | 
      Select-Object -First 1

# Increment the highest letter by 1 (the next letter, alphabetically).
$fileLetter = if (-not $fileLetter -or $fileLetter.Length -gt 1) {
    'a'
  } else {
    [char] (1 + [char] $fileLetter)
  }

$renameFrom = $dir + "\file.xls"
$renameTo = (Get-Date).ToString('MMdd') + $fileLetter + "_file.xls"

Rename-Item $renameFrom $renameTo -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-replace` operator to extract the letter:

```
$lastLetter = (Get-ChildItem -Path $dir\*_file.xls).BaseName -ireplace '^(?:\d{4})?([a-z])_file$','$1' |Sort-Object |Select-Object -First 1
```

You can simplify your `switch` statement as well:

```
$firstLetter = (1 + $lastLetter[0]) -as [char]
if(![char]::IsLetter($firstLetter)){
    $firstLetter = 'a'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a similar function to what you're trying to achieve to determine the next available computer name in AD.  I've modified it to what I think you're trying to do:

```
function Find-NextAvailableName {
param(
    ## Expects full file path:  C:\folder\folder\file.ext
    [string] $Fullname
)
    ## Break the fullname up into it's constituent parts
    $Path  = Split-Path $Fullname
    $File  = Split-Path $Fullname -Leaf

    ## Create the string representation of the deisred date format
    $FileDtm = [datetime]::Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

    ## Loop through the numeric-encoded representations of the lower case alphabet
    foreach ($i in (97..122)) { 
        ## convert to the integer to a char
        $letter = [char]$i 

        ## Construct the theoretical filename and path+filename
        $TestFileName = "$($FileDtm)_$($letter)_$($File)"
        $TestPath     = "$Path\$TestFileName"

        ## If the created file does NOT exist, break
        if (-not(Test-Path $TestPath)) {
            break
        }
    }

    ## return the last iterated $date_$letter_$filename that didn't exist
    return $TestPath
}

    ## Example
    $f = gi c:\users\me\desktop\somefile.ext
    Find-NextAvailableName -Fullname $f.FullName
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
(dir .\test -Filter *file.xls | select -last 2)[0]
```

If the files are sorted by a name, the select -last 1 will always return file.xls, because all other files have a number prefix. 
the code will return an array with two last files, the first index [0] will contain your file and the second file.xls